# Raising javascript events in ASP.NET user control

Tags: asp.net, javascript, user-controls

Is it possible to raise a "custom event" in an ASP.NET user control and to subscribe to the event in the calling page? This way I can have any containing page react to changes in a user control without having to do a partial or full postback.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to mix server-side code with client-side code.  You're probably better off using the built-in javascript events:

> ```
> control.Attributes.Add("onclick", "mgr.Click();"); //server-side
>
> //Javascript:
> var mgr = new Object();
> mgr.Click = new function(e) { //...
> ```

That said, with sufficient effort and a lot of hackery, you could probably get it to render out enough javascript and use AJAX calls to possibly acheive the effect; but it probably wouldn't be worth it; and isn't built-in.

Or - if your aim is to raise custom events server-side (rather than client-side) and handle them in javascript, render out calls to the functions:

> ```
> this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script type=\"text/javascript\">mgr.Filter('people');</script>"));
> ```

Comment: isn't that ASP.NET's M.O.? mixing client-side and server-side?